# Display is ADDING UP with TABLELAYOUT

Tags: android, view, tablelayout, tablerow

I am creating a calendar using tablelayout as my display to the screen. However when I need to update the display with either new month or year being selected by the user, it only adds up to the previouse stored data into the table.

HERE is my code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.main);

    table = new TableLayout(this);

    FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(         
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,         
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT); 
    table.setLayoutParams(lp);
    table.setStretchAllColumns(true); 
    rowLp2 = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(         
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,         
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,         
            1.0f);
    cellLp2 = new TableRow.LayoutParams(         
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,         
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,         
            1.0f);
   // cellLp3 = new TableRow.LayoutParams(arg0, arg1)
setYYMMDD(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
    leadGap = new GregorianCalendar(yy, mm, 1).get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1;
  //calling methods
    header();
    weeks();
    //setLeadGap(2011, 2);
    days(dom[mm]);


    setContentView(table);
}

private void days(int noDays)
{
    TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
    int d=1;
    nRow = (leadGap > 3) ? nRow+1 : nRow;
    //textMonth.setText(Integer.toString(nRow));
    for (int r = 0; r <nRow ; ++r) 
    {     
        row = new TableRow(this);
        if (r==0)
            {   int l = 0;
                for (int f = 1; f<7; ++f)
                {
                    if( l <leadGap)
                    {
                            TextView v = new TextView(this);
                            v.setText("");

                            row.addView(v, cellLp2);

                            l++;
                    }
                    if (l == leadGap)
                    {
                        Button v = new Button(this);
                        v.setText(Integer.toString(d));
                        row.addView(v, cellLp2);
                        d++;
                    }
                    row.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(55, 254, 55));

                }
            }
            else
            {

                for (int f = 0; f < 7; ++f)     
                {  

                        if (d <= noDays)
                        {
                            //Button btn = new Button(this);  
                            //btn.setText(Integer.toString(d));         
                            //row.addView(btn, cellLp2);
                            Button v = new Button(this);
                            v.setText(Integer.toString(d));
                            row.addView(v, cellLp2);

                            row.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(55, 254, 55));
                            d++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            TextView btn = new TextView(this);  
                            btn.setText("");         
                            row.addView(btn, cellLp2);

                        }


                }
            }
        table.addView(row, rowLp2); 
    } 

}

private void header(){
    headertbl= new TableLayout(this);
    btnMonthPos = new Button(this);
    btnMonthPos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {            
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {   
            if (iMonth > 10)
            {
                iMonth = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                iMonth += 1;
            }
            setLeadGap(iYear, iMonth);
            days(dom[iMonth]);



            textMonth.setText(months[iMonth]);   
            //recompute();
        }


    });   
textMonth = new TextView(this);
btnMonthNeg = new Button(this);
    btnMonthNeg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {            
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {   
            if (iMonth < 1)
            {
                iMonth = 11;
            }
            else
            {
                iMonth -= 1;
            }
            textMonth.setText(months[iMonth]);          
        }        
    });   
btnYearPos = new Button(this);
    btnYearPos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {            
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {   
            iYear += 1;
            textYear.setText(Integer.toString(iYear));  
            leadGap = new GregorianCalendar(yy, mm, 1).get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1;
            //sunBtn.setText(Integer.toString(leadGap));
        }        
    });
textYear = new TextView(this);
btnYearNeg = new Button(this);
    btnYearNeg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {            
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {   
                iYear -= 1;
                textYear.setText(Integer.toString(iYear));          
            }        
        }); 

//setting values during loading
btnMonthPos.setText("++");
textMonth.setText(months[mm]);
btnMonthNeg.setText("--");
btnYearPos.setText("++");
textYear.setText(Integer.toString(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)));
btnYearNeg.setText("--");

TableRow headerRow = new TableRow(this);
headerRow.addView(btnMonthPos, cellLp2);
headerRow.addView(textMonth, cellLp2);
headerRow.addView(btnMonthNeg, cellLp2);
headerRow.addView(btnYearPos, cellLp2);
headerRow.addView(textYear, cellLp2);
headerRow.addView(btnYearNeg, cellLp2);

headertbl.addView(headerRow, rowLp2);

 table.addView(headertbl);

}

private void weeks()
{
    String[] weekName = {"Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat"};
    tblWeek = new TableLayout(this);
    TableRow rowWeek = new TableRow(this);

    for (int i = 0; i<1; i++)
    {
        rowWeek = new TableRow(this);
        for (int j=0; j<weekName.length;j++)
        {
            TextView day = new TextView(this);
            day.setText(" "+weekName[j]);
            day.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
            rowWeek.addView(day, cellLp2);
        }
        rowWeek.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        tblWeek.addView(rowWeek, rowLp2);
    }

     table.addView(tblWeek);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider deleting the old tablerows before adding new rows in weeks() day() and other function to the table(Tablelayout)

Comment: hello, thank for the response. My problem now is I don't know to delete rows from my previous table/view. I tried looping using removeView(row) but it only gives me error. Please help. Thanks

Comment: i finally got it. thanks for the idea. I deleted the last row of my table which works fine. thanks. again.

Comment: if yo got the answer then mark it as answered so that it will be help for other s